# Show time(timestamp) only when check in is selected and then start timer(seconds)

Tags: time, onchange

Choose Option                   
        Check in
         Cancelled by pt 
         Cancelled by center

here is my Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function filter_seconds(date){
      return date.replace(/(\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})\:\d{2}/, '$1')
      var checkin=date;
      var check_in =$('.myStat-'+checkin).val();
      
      if (check_in != '04-checked in'){
      
        $('.myStat-'+checkin).prop(true)
      
      
      }else{
      $('.myStat-'+checkin).prop(false)
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it properly, please help. thank you.

Comment: by the way here is my HTML:
<body>
    <input  id="date"/>
 <select id="myStat-" onchange="document.getElementById('date').value = filter_seconds(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language))">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Option</option>     
  <option value="04-checked in">Check in</option>
  <option value="02-cancelled by pt"> Cancelled by pt </option>
  <option value="01-cancelled by center"> Cancelled by center</option>
  <option value="03-missed"></option>
    </select>
  </body>